# How do I use p4merge from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, svn, macos, merge, perforce

I would like to use the p4merge tool from Xcode in an SVN setup. Asking for trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here:
http://wiki.changesapp.com/index.php/Application_Integration#XCode_2.5_.26_3

1. Go to the "SCM" section in XCode's preferences.
2. Select the "Options" tab.
3. Select "Other..." in the pop-up for "View comparisons using:"
4. In the open panel, hit slash (/). In the field that pops up, type in: /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge

Comment: +1 : Usefull tips, I'll use this one later when my XCode will be configured to use git.